# How to format mui datepicker to 'mm-Mon-yyyy'?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I am using material-ui and didn't found any method to change the date format for the in-library date picker.
So I used different library 'mui/pickers' and still its not formating to the desired format i.e. `mm-Mon-yyyy` Eg:- `23-Sep-2020`.

I tried using `date-fns` as a util library to parse date with format `mm-Mon-yyyy` but got an error of invalid format.

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use correct format which is `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Also, you should use `openTo="year"` for Date of Birth and specify views in this order `views={["year", "month", "date"]}`

```
<DatePicker
      disableFuture
      label="Date of birth"
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={handleDateChange}
      openTo="year"
      format="dd-MMM-yyyy"
      views={["year", "month", "date"]}       
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

The MUI folks recommend using moment.js or something similar.

https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/parsing

Using moment, you could parse a date to that format by using this syntax:

```
moment().format(DD-MMM-YYYY)
```

Comment: using the momentjs to just parse the date is a bit overkill as its bundle size is way to bigger than `date-fns`. So future viewers, consider other util library than moment if you are not using it already in your stack.

Comment: This is completely and utterly accurate from @Bond007. Moment themselves actually agree with this and advise to only utilize them under specific conditions.

Comment: hello, how can i pass data like this to the date ranger picker? Like when i want to update the date, how to show the previously formatted data to the component and update it with new selected one?